# Reading from Bluetooth socket

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sockets, bluetooth

I have a problem with reading from Bluetooth socket. I create the socket:

```
private OutputStream outputStream;
private InputStream inStream;
socket=device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuids[0].getUuid());
socket.connect();
outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
inStream = socket.getInputStream();
```

After connection is established I send some instructions to the Bluetooth device after which I need to get an answer back(answer is always the same 5 bytes). But from time to time when I do this:

```
byte[] packetBytes = new byte[5];
inStream.read(packetBytes);
```

the app freezes.
I tried inputstream.available and used it with previous devices, but it would always return 0 here.
And I tried waiting before reading but still nothing. When I try those same commands on PC I get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody that is having the same problem as me. For now the solution that I am using is a new Thread that constantly reads from an input socket with inStream.read(packetBytes);

When something is read we just send it to our main Thread to be processed.